# how do I use ledger nano s with docker version of tezos?

Tags: baking, ledger, docker

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and I spun up carthagenet version of tezos with docker. But I'm not sure how I would hook up the ledger nano s to run with the mainnet version of this.